# How to get the records from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, outer-join

Hi I am new to the Database, and i am trying to get the records from the multiple tables, but depending upon there selection following is my tables

```
 Table1

  Column1      Column2
    1             10
    2             25 
    3             23
    4             15
    5              7


  Table2

  Column1      Column2
    2             15 
    3             13
    5             17

  Table3

  Column1      Column2
    2             45
```

Resultant Table should have records like

```
       Column1      Column2
         1             10
         2             45
         3             13
         4             15
         5             17
```

i am trying but not got the output yet. Any help or the direction to work out this output will be great help.

---

**UPDATE**

What i want is get the all rows from table1 then if table2 contains the matching records then it will remove the matching records form the resultset and add the table2 matching records and then same is repeated by table3.

Comment: @Curiosity- so you want maximum value of column2 for each column1 value right?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP No.I have updated the question please look at it

Comment: You need to define _matching_. All columns contain prime numbers? Column2 is evenly divisible by Column1 in a different table? Have equal Column1 values?

Comment: @HABO the data is dummy randomly inserted, the tables have column1 is common field between them

Comment: @Curiosity Could you please provide a better example explaining your requirement, if you dont mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the Below Code and Try

```
select * from table1 where column1 not in  ( select column1 from table2 union select column1 from table3)
union 
select  * from table2 where column1 not in  (select column1 from table3)
union
select  * from table3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT t1.column1, COALESCE(t3.column2,t2.column2,t1.column2) 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.column1=t2.column1
LEFT JOIN t3 on t1.column1=t3.column1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select x.col1,max(x.col2) from (

select * from #t1
union
select * from #t2
union 
select * from #t3 
)x
group by x.col1
```

## [see it in action](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13554)

Comment: This is not about getting the max value rather i want that the table2 will override all the matching records from the table1 and then table3 will override the all the matching records from the resultset

Comment: By getting max it will only get the records with the column2 max values thats not what i want. Let me update the question so you can understand it

Comment: I didn't downvote this and I suggest that others do not either as it was answered before the OP changed the question.  At the time, it was reasonable.

Comment: Agreed, @dan. Upvoted as it was a fairly good answer to the original question, considering. That said, this is a danger in answering unclear questions.